# PySimpleGUI tree doesn't Insert data into tree

Tags: python, tree, pysimplegui

I have been working on this tree in PysimpleGUI, suddenly the `insert` method decides to stop working when I give it a list full of data. I debugged nearly everything about it, the function `insert` itself stopped working or adding anything to tree data. Here is code

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from services import HandlePacks

Cardpacks = HandlePacks()
card_packs = Cardpacks.get_packs()
treeData = sg.TreeData()
for pack_name, card_pack in card_packs:
    print("Adding pack:", pack_name)
    treeData.insert("", str(pack_name), str(pack_name), "", icon=None)
    for card in card_pack:
        card_name = card["name"]
        print("Adding card:", card_name)
        treeData.insert(str(pack_name), str(card_name), str(card_name), "", icon=None)
print(treeData)

sg.theme("LightGrey1")

tree = sg.Tree(
    treeData,
    font=("Helvetica", 16),
    col0_width=30,
    enable_events=True,
    show_expanded=False,
    key="-TREE-",
)

delete_button = sg.Button("Delete Pack", disabled=True)

layout = [
    [sg.Text("All your Packs:", font=("Calibri", 24))],
    [tree],
    [delete_button],
]

window = sg.Window("Memory Game", layout, size=(600, 500))

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (None, "Exit"):
        break

    if event == "-TREE-":
        selected_item = values["-TREE-"]
        if selected_item:
            delete_button.update(disabled=False)
        else:
            delete_button.update(disabled=True)

    elif event == "Delete Pack":
        selected_item = values["-TREE-"][0]
        Cardpacks.delete_pack(selected_item)

    window.refresh()


window.close()
```

I tried changing it from `Insert` to `insert` and it didn't help. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It didn't show us what the library `services` is, maybe there's something wrong for the `card_packs`, or it's **empty**.

I create a basic data to show how them inserted into the TreeData, then as the data of Tree element.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

kinds = {"Spades":"♠", "Hearts":"♥", "Diamonds":"♦", "Clubs":"♣"}
names = ["Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"]
card_packs = [[kind, [kinds[kind]+name for name in names]] for kind in kinds]

treeData = sg.TreeData()
for pack_name, card_pack in card_packs:
    treeData.insert("", str(pack_name), str(pack_name), [], icon=None)
    for card in card_pack:
        card_name = card
        treeData.insert(str(pack_name), str(card_name), str(card_name), [], icon=None)

sg.theme("LightGrey1")

tree = sg.Tree(
    treeData,
    font=("Helvetica", 16),
    col0_width=30,
    enable_events=True,
    show_expanded=True,
    key="-TREE-",
)
delete_button = sg.Button("Delete Pack", disabled=True)
layout = [
    [sg.Text("All your Packs:", font=("Calibri", 24))],
    [tree],
    [delete_button],
]
window = sg.Window("Memory Game", layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

window.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had my data saved in a way that didn't make it able for the data to be inserted. Now it works